# Use of `this` keyword while implementing Event Handling in Java

Tags: java, swing, this

```
 b1.addActionListener(this);
```

In this statement what is the use of '`this`' keyword and what reference will be passed via '`this`' keyword ? Please let me know with example, if possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124126/java-addactionlistenerthis
possible duplicate question

Comment: @leigero Spotted your question and Do not use chat shortcuts while posting a post ,next time onwords.

Comment: `this` points to the current instance of the class you are using.

Answer (score 2):

"this" means this object, if your write this statement it means that your class implements ActionListener

for example :

```
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

class test extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JButton someButton;


    test() {
        // create the button
        someButton = new JButton();
        // add it to the frame
        this.add(someButton);
        // adding this class as a listener to the button, if button is pressed 
        // actionPerformed function of this class will be called and an event 
        // will be sent to it 
        someButton.addActionListener(this);
    }   
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        test c = new test();
        c.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        c.setSize(300, 300);
        c.setVisible(true);
        c.setResizable(false);
        c.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource() == someButton)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you pressed somebutton");
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: 'this' means this *object.*

Comment: @EJP yeah you are right !!

Comment: @ShyamD URW, Accept an answer on ur Questions if they were enough

Answer (score 2):

[this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) referes to the current instance of object.

say your class `A` implements the `ActionListener`. then from your class if you add the listener then you can use this , as for inheritance rule your class is also a listener.

```
class A implements ActionListener{
    Button b;
    A(){
         b1 = new Button();
         b1.addActionListener(this);
    }
}
```

Here this is used because the currentobject is also a action listener

Comment: thank u StinePike,ur answer really helped me

Comment: @user2578593 you are welcome.. and welcome to the so... if you think the answer was helpful please upvote accept the answer

Comment: Sure,i will once i get enough reputation